# Get services extended from a certain interface

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Is possible to get all services extended from a certain interface in grails

So I can collect them within one service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you can do this by autowiring to `List` type. Let's say you have three implementations of an interface `BaseService` in `grails-app/services` as:

*grails-app/services/exampleapp/BaseService.groovy*

```
package exampleapp

interface BaseService {
}
```

*grails-app/services/exampleapp/OneImplService.groovy*

```
package exampleapp

class OneImplService implements BaseService {
}
```

*grails-app/services/exampleapp/TwoImplService.groovy*

```
package exampleapp

class TwoImplService implements BaseService {
}
```

Now, you can inject all implementations of `BaseSerive` as follows:

*grails-app/services/exampleapp/TestService.groovy*

```
package exampleapp

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

class TestService {

    @Autowired
    List<BaseService> baseServiceList

    void doSomething() {
        assert baseServiceList.size() == 2
    }
}
```

**Please note** that the above example is tested with Grails 5 web application. But, I would be surprised if this does not work in the previous versions of Grails.